# How to keep two decimal in my code

Tags: c#

How to keep two decimal places in rate?

```
double rate;

double pi = Math.PI;
rate = fuel / distance ;

Console.WriteLine("Your fuel consumption rate is " + rate * 100 + "lt" + "/100km");
```

Comment: no, it's not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can Display them as like the following, where [Math.Round()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you to store rounded decimal in `rate`

```
rate = Math.Round((fuel / distance),2);
Console.WriteLine("Your fuel consumption rate is {0} lt/100km", (rate * 100).ToString("#.##"));
```

Comment: Works fine, So now Let me know what is the reason for `-1`

Comment: Sorry, I didnt put any -1